# DataTable with paging

Tags: javascript, api, datatable

Hi I am trying to create a custom paging on my API but I am stuck without idea.

I have a complex DataTable Object on the API which is created using severla source of information and that is what I expose in my API http//:myapi/getdata/2

Anybody have an idea of how implement a paging on a DataTable. I was trying to use the datatable's select method but I am not sure that I can performance complex queries with it
Also I am returning my information in a JSON to use in a RadGrid

Thank you

Comment: For pagination, you always have to create a single query to get everything you want. That is often rather complicated. Please post the structure of your tables and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a datatable with pagination, sorting and filtering. I tried a lot to make it in a custom way. But that turned out to be cumbersome and time-consuming.
So I searched this jQuery plugin with which I could easily create datatables.
Here is the link :
[jQuery Datatbles plugin with PHP and MySQL](http://www.sharemycode.com/item/view/95/jquery-datatables-plugin-example-with-php-mysql)

Hope this plugin helps you to create your custom paging API :)